# How to Remove the href link in dom parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom

html code:

```
<tr class="dd1">
<td>Aug 27, 2013</td>

<td>
<a href="/schedule/1588-zimbabwe-vs-pakistan-1st-odi-match.php" class="url">Zimbabwe vs Pakistan</a><b>, 1st ODI</b>
</td>   

<td>
<a href="/venue/harare.php">Harare</a>
</td>
```

php code:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.cricschedule.com/format/odi.php');

$es = $html->find('table td');

echo "$ea[4]";
```

I want output like this:
Zimbabwe vs Pakistan, 1st ODI

But I'm getting output like This:
[Zimbabwe vs Pakistan](/venue/harare.php)**, 1st ODI**

Comment: [**If one of the below answers solve your problem, kindly mark it as the right answer as it will not only benefit yourself but others looking to solve their problems, see here how to do it**](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strip_tags` function on your string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.cricschedule.com/format/odi.php');
$es = $html->find('table td');

echo strip_tags($es[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
echo strip_tags($es[4]);
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`strip_tags()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.cricschedule.com/format/odi.php');
$es =  $html->find('table td');
echo strip_tags( $ea[4] );
```

Comment: Why strip_tags you're already using the right tool just make so it reads value of `a` instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str_replace(",",".",trim(rtrim(strip_tags('<a href="/schedule/1588-zimbabwe-vs-pakistan-1st-odi-match.php" class="url">Zimbabwe vs Pakistan</a>'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to:
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/
(click scraping slashdot)

do

```
$es[4]->plaintext;
```